# Changes to php.ini not reflected in PHP's phpinfo()

Tags: php, xampp, php-ini

I just can't get php_info() values to change on my localhost setup, or the related [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) maximum file size.

So I have located the PHP file that [phpinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) states is being loaded. I have changed the three parameters:

upload_max_filesize

post_max_size

memory_limit

Saved the file, restarted Apache and MySQL, reloaded the phpinfo() page... no changes.

I've also tried putting a [.htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) file in the web root folder with changes to these parameters. This is reflected in *phpinfo* in the local value (the master value still says 2M for maximum upload size), and then when I go to phpMyAdmin the maximum upload size is still 2M...

I've looked for a php.ini file in C://windows as this is where phpinfo() states the master value is derived from. But there isn't any *php.ini* file there. So I created one with the values I wanted... no success!

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check that you’re editing the _right_ php.ini – phpinfo will tell you which one is used.

Comment: Try using `ini_set()` directly in php file. And make sure you are editing *right* php ini file.

Comment: phpinfo() and ini_set both state:'Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS','Loaded Configuration File: C:\xampp\php\php.ini'. So I'm editing C:\xampp\php\php.ini but no changes are occuring

Comment: I had this line uncommented, it needs to be commented Default Value: `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED`

Answer (score 25):

I came across the same issue.

Check if [php-fpm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Installation_and_configuration) is running by this command:

```
ps aux | grep php-fpm
```

php-fpm stands for "FastCGI Process Manager" for PHP and it was probably built in your system.
If so, you have to restart it. Assuming you are on a Linux system type:

1. For [Red Hat Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux), [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS), [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29), etc.

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service
   ```
2. For [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian)-based systems (like [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29))

   ```
   sudo service php-fpm restart
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
   ```

Comment: You are my hero. This was exactly my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Works fine, Kudos @Nikos Gkikas

Answer (score 3):

Don't do what I did... I changed max_input_vars from 1000 to 10000 but never noticed that the line was commented out by default.

; max_input_vars = 10000

I couldn't figure out why the value displayed in phpinfo() wouldn't change.

Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to look for `php.ini-development` / `php.ini-production`? If you update `php.ini-development` and then remove the `-development` then you should be good to go I believe.

Don't do what I did though and update the `php.ini-development` file and forget to remove the `-development`... I spent far too long wondering why the settings weren't updating!

Comment: Yes both these files exist in the directory along with C:\xampp\php\php.ini. But there's no point in changing the name and replacing the php.ini file that already exists in that directory is there?

Answer (score 0):

That happen for me, php.ini changes do not affect in phpinfo()

The reason is, that several php-fpm installed into the system and command was not reload config

```
service php-fpm restart
```

Proper command to reload service php74-php-fpm restart in my case:

```
service php74-php-fpm restart
```