# Changes in PHP.ini dosent reflect in phpinfo()

Tags: php, lampp, upload-max-filesize, move-uploaded-file

I have a problem that I can't seem to fix. I would really appriciate any help!

I am trying to make a script to upload files using the function `move_uploaded_file`, and it dosent work.

So I tried to change `php.ini` but theses changes dosent reflect in `phpinfo()`???

**I am using Ubuntu with Lampp php8, but I am quite new to linux**

- I have restarted the computer
- I am using the `php.ini` which is defined in phpinfo "Loaded
  configuration file"
- I have set `php.ini` permission to `777`
- There is no `.htaccess`
- I don't have PHP-FPM installed or Nginx
- There is no other php.ini in the lampp directory
- Read somewhere that in PHP8 doesn't allow changes so you need to make a new php.ini, and in the php ini it says: *"Name for user-defined `php.ini` (`.htaccess`) files. Default is ".user.ini"
  ;user_ini.filename = ".user.ini"*
- BUT when I touch `.user.ini` in terminal, nothing gets created.

[image]

Any ninjas out there, that can help me?

Comment: Hey Glen, _it dosen't work_ is not a very helpful problem description. Would you mind sharing what exactly doesn't work (any error messages)? Please read [ask].

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49908572/9074272).

Comment: Hi.  I was so obsessed with the php.ini that i forgot to write about this..
So I´m testing this script at my hosting provider instead of my local lampp server.... 
Here is the link to phpinfo: https://basisit.dk/test/index.php

the function move_uploaded_file returns FALSE.   
nothing gets moved 

You can test and see vardump here:
https://basisit.dk/test/file_upload.php
Further more the

Comment: `I restarted the computer`. Do you mean the server by that? If not, restart Apache, it will only load the new php.ini after that.

Comment: It means I restarted the computer completely.   So I was sure everything was restarted including the apache

Comment: Status is that I got the file upload to work. 
I needed to move $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']  (Thanks to great support at simply.com)


BUT i still cant change my php.ini settings

Comment: If you change the configuration on any other server than your local computer, you can restart your own computer as often as you like - you need to restart the Apache process on your remote webserver

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "it doesnt work"? You haven't shared any PHP code, nor any error message